# Using bcrypt.compare is returning false always

Tags: mysql, node.js, bcrypt

I am storing the users in a mysql table called users and the password is being encrypted with bcrypt

All is going well at time of encrypting the password but at time of comparing the password with the user input, is always false, and I dont know how to fix it

Aqui dejo un gist con todo lo relevante de lo que explico

- https://gist.github.com/sarmanulco/49e582ab0317e1c542f30acf8d1f69eb

Please help

Comment: Please paste the relevant code in your post instead of linking to repository

Comment: Why suggesting to use MySQL's `password()` for application passwords which provide little security against rainbow tables and GPU bruteforcing ? @juergend

Answer (score 1):

Your code example doesn't show where you are calling `bcrypt.hash` and storing the password, so it's hard to tell where the problem lies.

If you are debugging this locally, you must know what the password actually was; try taking the password hash from the database and running `bcrypt.compare('the real password', 'password hash from db')` in the node console and see what it returns.

The problem almost certainly is:

1) You are saving the password hash incorrectly.

2) You are comparing the password hash with the wrong thing.

3) It's working fine and you just aren't entering the right password.

The trick will be figuring out which one.

Comment: Is very strange

Answer (score 0):

`SQL
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users (
    user_id int primary key auto_increment not null,
    first_name varchar(30),
    last_name varchar(100),
    pass varchar(50)
) character set utf8;`

The problem was with the column text, that was configured to 50 characters as the maximum, i changed it to text